# how to change my website name in sharepoint from one url to another

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, iis, alternate-access-mapping

How to change the URL of a sharepoint web site from http://testsite.org to http://testsite1.org.

Answer (score 1):

Its Depend,

1. If it is the root level site collections as you mentioned(http://testsite.org), then simply you need to create the new DNS entry and point to WFE or Load balancer. Update the AAM settings, Update the IIS binidings if any.
2. If it is not root level site collection But Host Name Site collections then create new URL and use [Set-SPSiteUrl](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219633(v=office.15).aspx) command to set the new URL.
3. Lastly if it is path based non root site then, You have to take the backup of current site and restore it to new url.